# trouble understanding interruption with MSP430 in assembly

Tags: assembly, interrupt, msp430, isr

I don´t understand why in this code reti is used two times, and why the jmp is called to P1.1 then the jmp to P1.2 isn´t called. Is this an error?

Thank you.

```
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------
P1ISR   add.w &P1IV, PC 
        reti 
        reti 
        jmp     P1_1 
       ;jmp    P1_2 

P1_2   xor.b #L2, &P9OUT 
       bit.b #S1, &P1IN 
       jnz P1_2Fin 
       xor.b #L1, &P1OUT 
P1_2Fin reti

P1_1   xor.b #L1, &P1OUT 
       xor.b #S1, &P1IES 
       reti


.intvecPORT1_VECTOR, P1ISR
```

Comment: Actually it looks like the first instruction, `add.w &P1IV, PC` is doing a computed jump (or C `switch`) which then takes you to one of the 4 following instructions, two of which simply return. The `jmp P1_2` is not needed because `P1_2` itself is right there. I assume `P1IV` is some sort of mode control.

Comment: @Jester which 4 instructions are you refering to? Also, then `P1_2` is not ignored by the `jmp P1_2`?

Comment: The 4 instructions after the `add.w` are each handling a separate case. The `JMP P1_2` is not needed because it would jump to where the cpu is going anyway. If you had other cases as in the more complete example in the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63303710/547981), then you'd need that jump too. But since it is the last case in your code, you don't need the jump.

Comment: @Jester i thought that by doing `jmp P1_1` the cpu was skipping `P1_2`. how the jmp works then? thank you very much

Comment: Yes, the `jmp P1_1` is skipping over the `P1_2`. These handlers are for different cases, they don't run at the same time.

Comment: @Jester can you explain this different cases? thank you a lot

Comment: As you can read in the answer below, the `P1IV` value tells you which pin generated the highest priority interrupt in `P1`. So these cases allow you to handle a single pin at each invocation. If you have both `P1_1` and `P1_2` active, you will first get a handler invocation with `P1IV = 4` so you take the `JMP P1_1`. When you are done, the handler is again invoked but this time with `P1IV = 6` so you get to the `P1_2` case.

Comment: @Jester ok, Seems I don't understand how this code is read... I understand about the priority, but how does the jump work then? The first `RETI` the value is 0, after the second, the value is 2, and then after the `JMP`, the value is 4, meaning P1_1 vector

Comment: It's not **after**. The `P1IV` value tells you which pin generated the interrupt. It's an input. Think of your code block as `switch(P1IV) { case 0: reti; case 2: reti; case 4: goto P1_1; case 6: /* P1_2 */` }

Comment: @Jester thank you very much with that explanation and i have understood the `P1IV`. Now i have another question, i have seen these examples using `P1IFG`, when do you use each one?

Answer (score 2):

The User's Guide of your MSP chip says:

> **Port Interrupts**
>
> […] All P1 interrupt flags are prioritized, with P1IFG.0 being the highest, and combined to source a single interrupt vector. The highest priority enabled interrupt generates a number in the P1IV register. This number can be evaluated or added to the program counter to automatically enter the appropriate software routine. Disabled P1 interrupts do not affect the P1IV value.
> […]
> Any access (read or write) of the lower byte of the P1IV register, either word or byte access, automatically resets the highest pending interrupt flag. If another interrupt flag is set, another interrupt is immediately generated after servicing the initial interrupt. […]
>
> **Port Interrupt Software Example**
>
> The following software example shows the recommended use of P1IV and the handling overhead. The P1IV value is added to the PC to automatically jump to the appropriate routine. The P2IV is similar.
>
> The numbers at the right margin show the necessary CPU cycles for each instruction. The software overhead for different interrupt sources includes interrupt latency and return-from-interrupt cycles, but not the task handling itself.
>
> ```
> ;Interrupt handler for P1                           Cycles
> P1_HND   ...             ; Interrupt latency            6
>          ADD  &P1IV,PC   ; Add offset to Jump table     3
>          RETI            ; Vector 0: No interrupt       5
>          JMP  P1_0_HND   ; Vector 2: Port 1 bit 0       2
>          JMP  P1_1_HND   ; Vector 4: Port 1 bit 1       2
>          JMP  P1_2_HND   ; Vector 6: Port 1 bit 2       2
>          JMP  P1_3_HND   ; Vector 8: Port 1 bit 3       2
>          JMP  P1_4_HND   ; Vector 10: Port 1 bit 4      2
>          JMP  P1_5_HND   ; Vector 12: Port 1 bit 5      2
>          JMP  P1_6_HND   ; Vector 14: Port 1 bit 6      2
>          JMP  P1_7_HND   ; Vector 16: Port 1 bit 7      2
>
> P1_7_HND                 ; Vector 16: Port 1 bit 7
>          ...             ; Task starts here
>          RETI            ; Back to main program         5
>
> P1_6_HND                 ; Vector 14: Port 1 bit 6
>          ...             ; Task starts here
>          RETI            ; Back to main program         5
> ...
> ```

Comment: thank you, i had seen that already but i still don´t understand it. Why is the `reti`used after the `add`?

Comment: Look at the comment after the RETI.

Comment: i don´t understand the commentary. can you explain what it means? `RETI            ; Vector 0: No interrupt´. Is it related to the interrupt source?